# Hibernate OGM vs. Kundera

Tags: jpa, nosql, kundera, hibernate-ogm

Does anyone have a feedback on the use of Hibernate OGM vs. Kundera ? I know these 2 frameworks are providing Java Persistence (JPA) support for NoSQL solutions, and I would like to benefit from the experience of someone who studied both. It sounds like Kundera supports much more NoSQL DataSource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it is not a direct answer to your question, and because I have no detailed knowledge on Hibernate OGM, I would like to leave you some points concerning Kundera (if this helps you in some way). Kundera has several interesting points:

- support of multiple datastores
- very simple to setup
- very elegant in terms of code handling (you write very few Kundera code)
- JPA compliant
- performant

Apart from this, the Kundera team is very responsive and releases new versions in a very regular basis (every 2 months or so there is a new release!). These releases are made to support new features of supported datastores... this is especially important because many of these data stores (Cassandra, etc.) are still being very actively developed.

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know If the question is still of interest, but i used hibernate-ogm lately and found a very interesting point to consider:

you can mix it with the usual hibernate. I wrote a little test programm and can use mysql, postgresql(orm) and MongoDB(ogm) so far with just a little difference in the persistence.xml file.

For me that makes it very easy to test not only different databases, but different types of databases as well :)